# Different ways of pin access

Tags: beaglebone-black

I'm currently reading [introduction to PRU](http://mythopoeic.org/bbb-pru-minimal/)

And I paid attention to this sentence:

> **fast IO** -- Many of the pins have special IO modes for direct access by
>   the PRU. These work much faster than memory-mapped IO from the main
>   processor.

Why is direct access to pins by the PRU, so much faster than memory-mapped IO way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is direct access to pins by the PRU, so much faster than
>   memory-mapped IO way?

The Beagle-thing has a regular processor and two fast CPUs running at 200 MHz. Theynare called PRUs and the document you linked says this about the PRU (quite close to the top): -

> It is an independent CPU with its own memory and instruction set. It
>   can run its own program, completely independent of the Linux kernel on
>   the main CPU. It's fast (200MHz clock), all the instructions take
>   known constant times and you have it all to yourself, so you can use
>   it for things that require a hard realtime response. The 'bone has two
>   PRUs.

So you can use fast IO from the PRUs or slower IO that is memory mapped to the main processor but the main processor is slower because it's running the linux operating system.

The PRU IO is likely faster because hardware wise the pins connect directly to the CPU chip whereas memory-mapped IO (from a labouring CPU running linux) might only talk to its IO chips every few milliseconds.

Comment: So you say that even main processor which runs up to 1 GHz (running Linux) is slower than PRUs which are 200 MHz?

Comment: That is what the document says and remember, a system running linux (or any operating system) is compromised for applications that require high speed IO because it is the operating system that decides when IO is to be read or written. The PRUs are dedicated to the task in hand and don't concern themselves with trying to service multiple things happening simultaneously.